# How to develop multiple versions of app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am making an app in Android. I have a basic version which works. I want to add additional features to it like GPS, better GUI. I code in Android Studio. I want a copy of my basic version to exist, so I can go back to it if something goes wrong. Without creating another project and copying everything from the basic, how can I go about making another version of code?

For example, MIT App Inventor has checkpoints, which will save the project till that point and allow you to edit  new copy of app but in same project. I want to do this in Android Studio, how so I do this?

Comment: Git can be used to do things like this, and is integrated into Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

What actually you are looking for is Version Control System. Mostly every VCS supports tags that you can apply to your code (like checkpoints you mentioned). Then you can go back to these tags and continue to work with previous state of code. The most popular VCS today is git. Android Studio supports almost every VCS.

If for some reasons you don't want to use VCS you can try "Local history" which is a feature of Android Studio. You can find it in the top menu under VCS tab. It supports "labels" that act like tags in regular VCS or "checkpoints". But functionality is quite limited, so I would recommend to stick to git or other VCS.